# Equivalent to MATLAB's freqz in Julia

Tags: matlab, filter, julia, signal-processing

MATLAB has a nice library of digital signals processing functions that give you a lot of control over linear-time invariant systems. My goal is to view the frequency response of a system governed by two vectors `a=[1, -1.1, 0.46]` and `b=[1, 0.04, 0.76]`.

To do this in MATLAB, I'd just use the [`freqz(b,a)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html) and get back the frequency response `h` and frequencies evaluated `w`. I am working in Julia and am using the `DSP` package, so I'm attempting to use the [`DSP.Filters.freqresp`](https://docs.juliadsp.org/stable/filters/#DSP.Filters.freqresp) function. To set this up, I define the vectors and import the relevant package:

```
a=[1, -1.1, 0.46]
b=[1, 0.04, 0.76]
using DSP.Filters : freqresp

h, w = freqresp([b,a])
```

When I run this I get the error

```
MethodError: no method matching freqresp(::Vector{Int64})
```

How should I be implementing this function to obtain a valid result?

Comment: @Shayan There are two doc pages for `freqz` and I linked the wrong one. From the docs "`[h,w] = freqz(b,a,n)` returns the `n`-point frequency response vector `h` and the corresponding angular frequency vector `w` for the digital filter with transfer function coefficients stored in `b` and `a`.". In my question I believe the filter is meant to be a low-pass with the coefficients from the difference equation. `freqz` gives the frequency response of the filter given the coefficients, from what I understand

Comment: Follow the documentation of each filter to find the best suit for your case. E.g., here is the doc for the [ZeroPoleGain](https://github.com/JuliaDSP/DSP.jl/blob/e44941164ea3b33e9db42494982e6ba58dcf009f/src/Filters/coefficients.jl#L13) filter and [PolynomialRatio](https://github.com/JuliaDSP/DSP.jl/blob/e44941164ea3b33e9db42494982e6ba58dcf009f/src/Filters/coefficients.jl#L97). Henceforth, we can come up with better help for the specified filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Shayan pointed me in the right direction by mentioning `PolynomialRatio`, as plugging in the `a` and `b` vectors give a representation that `freqresp` will accept. As a result, I get the same answer as in MATLAB

```
a=[1, -1.1, 0.46]
b=[1, 0.04, 0.76]

using DSP

z = PolynomialRatio(b,a)
h, w = freqresp(z)

mag = abs.(h)
phase = atan.(imag.(h)./real.(h))*180/pi
p1 = plot(w, mag)
xaxis!("")
yaxis!("Magnitude")

p2 = plot(w, phase)
xaxis!("Normalized Frequency")
yaxis!("Wrapped Phase [deg]")

plot(p1, p2, layout=(2,1))
```

Which gives

[image]

Comment: You can use the functions `angle` and `rad2deg` to compute the phase.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of the [ControlSystems.jl](https://juliacontrol.github.io/ControlSystems.jl/stable/) package for this:

```
julia> using ControlSystemsBase, Plots

julia> a=[1, -1.1, 0.46]
3-element Vector{Float64}:
  1.0
 -1.1
  0.46

julia> b=[1, 0.04, 0.76]
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 0.04
 0.76

julia> Z = tf(b,a,1)
TransferFunction{Discrete{Int64}, ControlSystemsBase.SisoRational{Float64}}
1.0z^2 + 0.04z + 0.76
---------------------
1.0z^2 - 1.1z + 0.46

Sample Time: 1 (seconds)
Discrete-time transfer function model

julia> bodeplot(Z)
```

[image]

The `bodeplot` plot recipe handles phase unrolling etc. for you.